# How to get value selected from select in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have a dropDownList like follwing:

```
<?php echo TbHtml::dropdownList('cls', $sel, CHtml::listData($classes, 'type_class', 'name_class')); ?>
```

That generates a select option like that:

```
<select id="cls" name="cls">
    <option value="1">Main Class</option>
    <option value="2">Other Class</option>
</select>
```

When I click on a button, I need to get the value, in my example 1 or 2.

The button is built like following:

```
echo $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'buttonType' => 'link',
    'context' => 'warning',
    'icon' => 'fa fa-file-pdf-o',
    'label' => 'Submit',
    'size' => 'small',
    'url' => array(
        '//wseder/excel/wws',
        'code_from_select' => $VALUE_THAT_I_NEED // here i need the value
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'pull-rigth btn-nxt-prv',
        'style' => 'margin-left:5px'
    )
), true);
```

How can I access to the value selected from the select?

Answer (score 0):

How I understand you creating select on html page and button on html page. When you click button you need get select val and put it in button. If so, you can not do it, because php do not have access to select val on html page. You should use javascript (jquery) to read select value and insert it where you need.